# Make UITextView clickable in CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UITextView (editable is false) in my CollectionViewCell, but when clicking on the TextView `didSelect` does not trigger, but clicking elsewhere on the cell does trigger. Is there something I need to add so that it will trigger?

Comment: why not setting `editable` to true and implementing the delegate method `textViewShouldBeginEditing` ? By that I believe you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Have you tried ignoring user interaction on the textView? Something like `textView. isUserInteractionEnabled = false` should pass the touches from the textView to the cell that contains it.